# In bash, how do I set a variable to encompass a variable number of command line arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I’m using bash shell.  I’m writing a script and I would like to capture a variable number of arguments passed to my script after and including argument #5.  So far I have this …

```
#!/bin/bash
…
declare -a attachments
attachments=( "$5" )
```

But what I can’t figure out is how to write the “attachments” line to encompass argument #5 and any arguments that follow that.  So in the following example

```
sh my_script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 “my_file1.csv” “my_file2.csv”
```

I would want attachments to consist of “my_file1.csv” and “my_file2.csv,” whereas in this example …

```
sh my_script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 “my_file1.csv” “my_file2.csv” “my_file3.csv”
```

I would want attachments to contain “my_file1.csv,” “my_file2.csv,” and “my_file3.csv.”

Comment: Firstly don't use those stupid quotes, secondly get the first 4 args and then `shift 4` and `attachments=( "$@" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual idiom is to capture the fixed arguments into variables, and then the remainder are available as `"$@"`:

```
srcdir="$1"; shift
destdir="$1"; shift
optflag="$1"; shift
barflag="$1"; shift

(cd "$destdir" && mv -t "$destdir" "-$optflag" "$@" )
```

This idiom easily extends should you find the need for a variable number of arguments preceding the list:

```
while [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]
do
    case "$1" in
      -foo) foo="$2";shift 2 ;;
      -bar) bar="$2";shift 2 ;;
      -baz) bar=true;shift 1 ;;
      --) shift; break;
    esac
done
# rest of arguments are in "$@"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
srcdir=$1
destdir=$2
optflag=$3
barflag=$4
attachments=( "${@:5}" )
```

Comment: I prefer this method, since it doesn't mess with the argument list itself. BTW, you can also extract arguments from the middle of the list, e.g. `"${@:5:3}"` will include 3 arguments starting at #5 (i.e. arguments 5, 6, and 7)